# Failed to authenticate to database while configuring authentication to GridfsTemplate in MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, gridfs

i am getting authentication failed while connecting to mongo database.i am using GridFsTemplate to store some image into Mongo here is the code

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("reqId") String reqId, HttpServletRequest request){

        MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
        CommonsMultipartFile multipartFile =  null; 
        String fileName = null;
        Iterator<String> iterator = multipartRequest.getFileNames();

        try {
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    String key = (String) iterator.next();
                    multipartFile = (CommonsMultipartFile) multipartRequest
                            .getFile(key);
                    DBObject metaData = new BasicDBObject();
                    int num = (int) ((Math.random() * 9000000) + 1000000);
                    metaData.put("reqId", reqId);
                    InputStream inputStream = null;
                    if (!multipartFile.isEmpty()) {

                            File convFile = new File(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
                            multipartFile.transferTo(convFile);
                            fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename()+""+num;
                            inputStream = new FileInputStream(convFile);
                            gridFsTemplate.store(inputStream, fileName,multipartFile.getContentType(), metaData);

                        }
                    }
                return "You successfully uploaded " + fileName + " into "
                + fileName + "-uploaded !";
                }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return "You failed to upload " + fileName + " => "
                            + e.getMessage();
        }
```

spring configuration

```
<bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
                <property name="host" value="localhost" />
                <property name="port" value="27017" />
            </bean>
            <bean id="mongoCredentials" class="org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials">
                <constructor-arg name="username" value="testuser" />
                <constructor-arg name="password" value="test" />
            </bean>

              <bean id="mongoDbFactory" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory">
                <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
                <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="testdb" />
                <constructor-arg name="credentials" ref="mongoCredentials" 
                <constructor-arg name="authenticationDatabaseName" value="admin" />
            </bean>

            <bean name="gridFsTemplate"
                class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.gridfs.GridFsTemplate">
                <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory" />
                <constructor-arg ref="converter" />
            </bean>
```

i am using bellow jars in my lib and build path

- mongo-java-driver-2.13.0.jar ,
  spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar,
  spring-data-mongodb-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar

in my pom.xml i have any entry for only **spring-data-mongodb-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar**

i am getting the bellow exception

> org.springframework.data.mongodb.CannotGetMongoDbConnectionException: Failed to authenticate to database [testdb], username = [testuser], password = [t**t]
>           at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils.doGetDB(MongoDbUtils.java:124)
>           at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils.getDB(MongoDbUtils.java:81)
>           at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory.getDb(SimpleMongoDbFactory.java:145)
>           at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory.getDb(SimpleMongoDbFactory.java:134)
>           at org.springframework.data.mongodb.gridfs.GridFsTemplate.getGridFs(GridFsTemplate.java:264)
>           at org.springframework.data.mongodb.gridfs.GridFsTemplate.store(GridFsTemplate.java:160)
>           at com.cisco.asestore.restful.controller.ToolDocsMongoController.handleFileUpload(ToolDocsMongoController.java:158)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
>           at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:201)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1517)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1474)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

i tried all the possible ways there are so many posts for how to configure authentication for MongoTemplate not for GridFsTemplate please help me to fix the issue

Comment: Can you please show the complete error logs...

Comment: hi karan, i have updated with complete stack trace

Comment: `Failed to authenticate to database [testdb], username = [testuser], password = [t**t]` ??